# Can a core data relationship have multiple destinations?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

I have a general class that has two properties: name and objects.  The objects property can have several different types of custom objects.

Is there a way to setup a to-many relationship on the objects property so it can contain several different types of objects?

I know I can use NSArchiver and a transformable type, but I was wondering if there's another way.

Comment: Why do you need to do it with one relationship? What kind of custom object? Are these collections of basic types, like Ints/Strings,... Then I would make an entity for each type of object. Having a lot of one to many relationships is no problem. If they contain more custom types, then I would rethink your approach. I try not to make Core Data angry.

Comment: I'll try to explain. I have ClassA with property arrayB; arrayB contains instances of ClassC. ClassC has property arrayD. Each instance of arrayD will have instances of ClassE OR ClassF OR ClassG. The problem is arrayD may contain instances of different classes, not just one class.

Comment: if you put a switch before the save and just check the first item in the array, you can save them as one of three core data entities. When fetching you just fetch all three and see what comes back.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would do that. Right now I load all objects from all entities (which is what I need) by loading only the top level object (ClassA from my last comment).

Comment: To elaborate : CoreData entity for ClassC has three one to many relationships, one to Entity "E", Entity "F", Entity "G" When saving you put a switch and when fetching you rebuild Array D from the fetch results off three related entities.

Comment: You would need to get the related core data objects as Arrays of those objects, iterate through those and add them to an Array that will them become D. or as an NSSet/NSMutableSet and use those methods

Comment: Oh I understand. I'm wondering, is that better than if I were to use a Transferable type for ClassE/F/G if I'm loading all objects anyway?

Comment: There is a difference between faulting every object and firing faults on all objects. If you mean by loading = faulting, then no my method will not be better. Loading ClassE/F/G into arrays will most likely fire a fault on a lot of stuff and load it all in ram. If the data you are loading will never exceed a couple of kilobytes then I wouldn't care too much about that

Comment: I am working with pictures at the moment and have to be very careful with what I load and how. I now use structs that mimic Core Data entities to store name/ID/Bools/... into ram without firing a fault on the image also stored in the entity. These structs also work as my intermediary types. My images and filtered images have separate entities in Core Data but get loaded into the same struct. This way I can have 2 classes but always have an array of one type. (which holds a lot of nils)

Comment: I'd imagine the data will exceed a few kilobytes at some point since it's all entered by the user.  By loading I mean I fetch the entity description for my top level object (there is only one) which should in turn load all it's properties into memory.  The app I'm working on is a "load all data" type of deal. It's useless if only some data is loaded.

Comment: When doing a fetch, all data is actually loaded as faults. When putting the data to use/assigning it to other stuff, you fire the fault. Aside from that Just fetching the top object is enough. You don't need to fetch ClassE/F/G. Just put a switch around building array D. if there are items in class E create D with E and so on.

Comment: Thank you. I think you've given me a direction to head in. :)

Comment: No problem. Can be hard to help without code, but can be hard to post code when things get more complex.

Comment: Another win for the multi-relationship and not archived is that you can predicate your fetches on those objects. Binary data is effectively useless for anything in the future without loading and processing into memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a relationship to different subentities, as a reference to an instance of a class can point to an instance of a subclass. But it is not possible to have a relationship to any instance as with `id`.

Important: Subentities are modeled into one table leaving sibling properties empty. That can lead to a very big table.

Instead of having binary data (which does not work, if it is a composing relationship) you can handle your situation with two properties, one containing the destination entity name and one akin of id. Of course, you need additional code to resolve such a relationship.

Comment: So could I have a to-many relationship pointing to ClassA and populate it with subclasses of ClassA?

Comment: Subentites, not subclasses! You can always populate entities with its class or subclass. But on disk there are only the properties described in the entity.

Comment: Subentities? I wasn't aware you could create one?

Comment: I thought so. :-) Select an (sub-)entity and open the data model inspector. You will find a setting *Parent Entity*.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you! I'll see if I can get this to work. :-)

Comment: Hmm so if I have a to-many relationship, let's call it "setA" in my CMAUserDefine entity and it's destination is EntityParent, I can insert entities whose parent is EntityParent into "setA" and everything will work as expected?

Comment: Okay, more time: Yes, you can insert subentities of `CMAUserDefine`.